# French Republican Calendar Converter (Romme Rule)

Tags: javascript

This is a French Republican Calendar / Gregorian Calendar converter I've written; it returns an accurate date for all the dates I've tested (mostly dates in the present age, although it also lines up with historical French Republican Dates, give or take a day- depending on whether or not they use the Romme Rule.

I'm wondering if anyone can notice any mistakes I've made in my implementation.

Thanks

````javascript
const months = [
  "Vendémiaire",
  "Brumaire",
  "Frimaire",
  "Nivôse",
  "Pluviôse",
  "Ventôse",
  "Messidor",
  "Thermidor",
  "Fructidor",
  "Prairial",
  "Germinal",
  "Floreal",
];

const sansculottides = [
  "Virtue",
  "Genius",
  "Labour",
  "Opinion",
  "Rewards",
  "Revolution",
];


function isLeapYear(year) {
  return (
    year % 4 === 0 &&
    (year % 100 !== 0 || year % 400 === 0) &&
    year % 4000 !== 0
  );
}

function toRepublicanCalendar(year, month, day) {
  let startYear = year;
  if (month < 9 || (month === 9 && day < 22)) {
    startYear--;
  }

  const startRepublican = new Date(startYear, 8, 22);
  const currentDate = new Date(year, month - 1, day);
  let dayOfYear = Math.floor(
    (currentDate - startRepublican) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
  );

  const daysInYear = isLeapYear(startYear) ? 366 : 365;
  if (dayOfYear >= daysInYear - 5) {
    const sansculottidesDay = dayOfYear - (daysInYear - 6);
    return {
      day: sansculottidesDay,
      month: "Sansculottides",
      year: startYear - 1791,
    };
  }

  if (isLeapYear(startYear)) {
    dayOfYear++;
  }

  const republicanMonth = Math.floor(dayOfYear / 30);
  const republicanDay = (dayOfYear % 30) + 1;
  return {
    day: republicanDay,
    month: months[republicanMonth],
    year: startYear - 1791,
  };
}
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Nice first question, a quick review;

- I would not pollute the global name scope with `months` and `sansculottides`, I would declare these locally under `toRepublicanCalendar`
- I like verbObject, so maybe `convertToRepublicanCalendar`
- I don't like writing calendar code myself, so I would go for leveraging standard JS

  ```
  function isLeapYear(year){
    return (new Date(year + "-02-29").getDate()===29);
  }
  ```
- This could use either a link explaining the logic of the republican calendar or comments inside the code with the republican calendar logic

Answer (score 1):

**Too many magic numbers**

Give names to Republican Calendar constants. Don't cop out by just adding comments. Some names will no doubt be "too long", but go a step further and work hard to shorten them to concise-yet-communicating. *It is an iterative process.*

**Group constants with objects**

`Republican.firstDay` instead of `startRepublican`, for example. This will help readers' understanding in calculations mixing Gregorian and Republican values. *Note how the object name give context to a more general property name*

Put constant definitions at the top of their functions.

**method Naming**

`toRepublicanCalendar` is fine IMHO. There is no confusion, everyone understands `toString` for example. This is especially true if the parameter(s) is(are) clearly a Gregorian date - e.g. a JS `Date` object.

`actionverbObject` - I agree with this general form for function/method names. This is the "active voice" in writing English. It is short, concise, direct. However using prepositions gets into passive voice. Could be `convertGregorian` but the emphasis of Republican dates is the proper perspective for this code.

**Domain Language**

Big thumbs up for `sansculottides` name. This is exactly what we mean when we say DSL - domain specific language. A very desirable trait is to have code - and especially the public API - to read in terms of the problem domain.

Did the Republicans name the first day of their new calendar system?

**Objects, Not Data Fragments**

Create a JS `Date` object and pass that into the conversion machine. Allow the UI to take M.D.Y but convert it to a Date object before using it. This effectively validates the input. Also makes for clean and unambiguous referencing - and reading - throughout the code.

**Global Scope**

Code reviews always mention keeping all those loose variables & constants out of global scope. Encapsulating them in objects does that, but it is not enough. Get all the code out of global scope. Ideally all JS code should be wrapped inside a single function (it's an object, really) so only the encapsulating function name is exposed globally.

Research [IIFE - Immediately Invoked Function Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE).  It's easier to do than to say.